# Fill missing date with previous entry

Tags: r, date, time

I have a character object containing dates that looks like this;

```
Dec-13-17 06:38AM
Dec-11-17 07:30AM
06:35AM
06:20AM  
06:15AM 
Dec-09-17 01:22PM
Dec-08-17 11:46AM 
05:20AM 
Dec-08-17 09:38AM
```

Problem I have is that a few of these entries are missing the date value. The 6:35, 6:20 & 5:15 are all missing Dec-11-17 and the 05:20AM is missing Dec-08-17.

I wrote quite a lengthy ifelse statement that would always look back to the next complete date by using `str_count()` to find the next complete datetime then using gsub to extract the date only part then paste it with the existing time entry like this;

```
paste0(gsub( " .*$", "", datetime), <existingdate>)
```

Its quite messy as it contains lots of nested ifelse statements but the problem is that I never know how many rows above the incomplete entry I have to look to extract the date from. As this data is scraped from the web my nested if else statements could be very long to accommodate this and I am sure there is a better way of doing this.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Please accept answer that helped to solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the input is `s` below, extract the date returning it or NA if none  giving `dat`.  Also extract the time giving `tim`.  Run `na.locf` on the date to fill in the missing dates and paste the date and time together.

```
s <- c("Dec-13-17 06:38AM", "Dec-11-17 07:30AM", "06:35AM", "06:20AM", 
  "06:15AM", "Dec-09-17 01:22PM", "Dec-08-17 11:46AM", "05:20AM", 
  "Dec-08-17 09:38AM")

library(zoo)
dat <-  ifelse(grepl("-", s), sub(" .*", "", s), NA)
tim = sub(".* ", "", s)
dattim <- paste(na.locf(dat), tim)
as.POSIXct(dattim, format = "%b-%d-%y %I:%M%p")
```

giving:

```
[1] "2017-12-13 06:38:00 EST" "2017-12-11 07:30:00 EST"
[3] "2017-12-11 06:35:00 EST" "2017-12-11 06:20:00 EST"
[5] "2017-12-11 06:15:00 EST" "2017-12-09 13:22:00 EST"
[7] "2017-12-08 11:46:00 EST" "2017-12-08 05:20:00 EST"
[9] "2017-12-08 09:38:00 EST"
```

Answer (score 1):

First get `NA` for entries without MDY information. Then use `tidyr::fill` to fill those `NA`s with previous entries.

```
# Using OPs data stored in df (column V1)
foo <- ifelse(grepl("^[A-z]", df$V1), sub(" .*", "", df$V1), NA)
# [1] "Dec-13-17" "Dec-11-17" NA          NA          NA          "Dec-09-17"
# [7] "Dec-08-17" NA          "Dec-08-17"

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.frame(foo) %>% 
    fill(foo) %>% 
    mutate(foo = paste(foo, sub(".* ", "", df$V1)))

#                 foo
# 1 Dec-13-17 06:38AM
# 2 Dec-11-17 07:30AM
# 3 Dec-11-17 06:35AM
# 4 Dec-11-17 06:20AM
# 5 Dec-11-17 06:15AM
# 6 Dec-09-17 01:22PM
# 7 Dec-08-17 11:46AM
# 8 Dec-08-17 05:20AM
# 9 Dec-08-17 09:38AM
```